# SimpleXML foreach doesn't work

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

I have following XML (source.xml):

```
<SHOP>
<SHOPITEM>
<ITEM_ID>3664</ITEM_ID>
<PRODUCT>Product n.1</PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT_NAME>Product n.1</PRODUCT_NAME>
<VARIANT_NAME/>
<MANUFACTURER>Jeffrey</MANUFACTURER>
<CODE>ABC123</CODE>
<EAN>123456789</EAN>
<DESCRIPTION>
Maybe later...
</DESCRIPTION>
<DESCRIPTION_HTML/>
<CATEGORIES>
<CATEGORY id="1" parent_id="0">ABx</CATEGORY>
</CATEGORIES>
</SHOPITEM>
<SHOPITEM>
...etc
```

And following code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("source.xml", NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);


foreach ($xml->shopitem as $shopitem) {

  echo  $shopitem->item_id;
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Even if I put echo 'a'; into foreach cycle, nothing appears. XML is valid. Tried var_dump($xml) and the XML looks to be loaded correctly. What is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: XML is case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Side note: you don't need `LIBXML_NOCDATA`; the only thing it does is make the output of `print_r` and other debugging functions slightly clearer, in some rare situations; it doesn't change the actual behaviour when using `echo` or getting the value into a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("source.xml", NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach ($xml->SHOPITEM as $shopitem) {

  echo  $shopitem->ITEM_ID;

}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm so happy to see it working after 2 hours of trying everything :)))